Explain the types of dividend distribution to me in plain English
On page 34 of "Essay Exam Writing for the California Bar Exam" by Basick Schindler (2nd edition), the book says the following:

Dividends are the distribution of cash, property, or stock that a shareholder may receive from the corporation. Dividends are given at the board's discretion. A distribution is disallowed if it would lead to insolvency or is disallowed in the articles. Types of dividend distribution:


(1) Preferred with dividend preference: Paid fist to preferred with dividend preference as to stated amount, then remaining amount is paid to common stock.


(2) Preferred and participating: Paid first to preferred and participating as indicated in preferred amount, then remaining amount is paid to common stock. (Preferred and participating stockholders also get a share of the dividends paid to common stockholders, if any).


(3) Preferred and cumulative: Paid first to preferred and cumulative as indicated for number of years not paid in the past, then remaining amount is paid to common stock.


(4) Cumulative if earned: Dividends cumulate only if the corporation's total earnings for the year are more than the total amount of preferred dividends that would need to be paid out for the year.


(5) Common stock (nonpreferred): Paid last and all shares are paid in equal amount.

The moment the book gets to the numbered list I get lost. I understand that there are different classifications of stock (preferred and common). But everything else confuses me. What is a "dividend preference"? "Participating" as in participating in what? And what is the difference between bullets 3 and 4?
Please help me understand the bullet list in plain English in a way that differentiates each bullet point from each other.

You might be confused by the order of the list. Bullet 5 is pretty much the default: everyone gets paid equally and there are no special classes of stock (well, perhaps for voting purposes, but this is about money).
Now, if we have a special situation where not everyone is paid equally, then some people are paid before others. The easiest situation is 1 - a preference. If there's not enough dividend to pay everyone a agreed-upon rate, the preferred stock is paid dividend first.
Now, "cumulative" is a variation. If one year a dividend payout is skipped, even with preferred stock you're out of luck. But with cumulative dividends, you retain a right to that old dividend before new dividends are paid out. So if a company didn't pay any dividends in 2023, they still need to pay the cumulative dividends of 2023 before paying any 2024 dividends (or in case of option 4, cumulative dividends for 2023 are paid after the preferred 2024 dividends, but before 2024 nonpreferred dividends). This means you're even more likely to receive this kind of dividend, albeit possibly with some delay.
"Preferred and participating" should be taken as just a label here. If you own such a share, you can get two dividend payments: both the preferred and the regular one.

You may think of 'participating' as 'participating in running the company' in the sense that 'the people running the company get to grab any leftover or extra money". But since it is a financial class not a management class, they don't have to actually participate in running the company -- only to participate in grabbing any leftover or extra money. It comes into play when there is leftover or extra money.
